# configuring how to pull data out of 3 tables with mysql

Tags: mysql, database

Here is how the the database is layout. I can connect to DB fine.
I had it pullling from database two things but adding a third i can not get it to pull. I just need some help if i could ..

```
database - mmoore_drupal

table 1

table name = content_type_uprofile

data
vid= 19723
nid =19674
field_name_value = matthew moore


table 2

table name  = location_instance

data

lid = 1521
vid = 19723
nid = 19674

table 3

table name = location

data

lid = 1521
street =
city =
country =
latitude =
longitude =
```

I am trying to pull name and then other info from  the other two tables. But mainly i need to have name and other information from location. I thought i had to have the other table to associate the connection. Any help is appreciated.

```
$query = "SELECT content_type_uprofile.field_name_value,location.street,location.city
    FROM location_instance,location,content_type_uprofile
       WHERE location_instance.lid = location.lid and                               location_instance.nid=content_type_uprofile.nid"

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['nid']."-".$row['street']. " - ". $row['city'];
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this SQL (explicit join syntax):

```
SELECT
  content_type_uprofile.nid,
  location.street,
  location.city
FROM
  content_type_uprofile
INNER JOIN location_instance
  ON (content_type_uprofile.nid = location_instance.nid)
INNER JOIN location
  ON (location_instance.lid = location.lid)
```

*The SQL that you posted is using [implicit join SQL syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins).*

I think for some reason, I think the line in your SQL:

```
WHERE location_instance.lid = location.lid and location_instance.nid=content_type_uprofile.nid
```

is filtering out all the rows from your result set.  I'm not sure because I avoid the implicit syntax.

You were also missing the `nid` field which your PHP code is looking for in the result set.

**As long as your data is correct (i.e. the fields that you are joining on have the right values), the SQL that I posted will work for you.**

Comment: You need to paste the SQL into a query tool: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/, http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/, and http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php are some popular free ones.  This will help you find the error.  I did not do this, but upon proofreading my SQL, I noticed an extra comma after `location.city`.  I corrected it.  please try again.

Answer (score -1):

You ever done something with `join`'s?

```
select *.locaition,
    *.content_type_uprofile
from location_instance li
inner join location l on l.lid = li.lid
inner join content_type_uprofile ctu on ctu.vid = li.vid
```

Comment: `location.*, content_type_uprofile.*` - You have them reversed.